# React native multi screen form

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hook-form

I need to create a **React Native** multi-screen form using **React Hook Form**. Here's an example: there are three screens, and the submit button is located on the first screen.

I want to gather all the data from all screens when the user clicks the submit button on the first screen. If there is an error, for example, on the second screen, the user will be navigated back to the second screen with the error.

I tried something like this

```
const { control, reset, handleSubmit, setValue, getValues, formState: { errors } } = useForm<ContractFormData>({
    resolver: yupResolver(contractFormSchema)
  })

  return {
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    setValue,
    control,
    errors,
    reset,
  }
```

Comment: It's better if you do one schema and form for each screen, this will allow you to scale and debug more easily

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.